# Trouble Finding Where I'm Going Wrong While Reading this Text File

Tags: c

I wrote this code to read in the following line from a text file: 
1019*/passed// 56.)100,/ 82//10 however when I print it afetr the sscanf function I only get the 1019 and the number 10 correctly , rest have garbage values , any idea why? I'd appreciate if someone could correct me, I even tried putting %d instead of just %[..] in the sscanf function but stil doesnt print out the desired values.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int main ()
{
char buffer[100];
char status[20];
int grades[4]= {0};
int id;
int j;
int k;
int temp;


FILE *pointer = fopen ("testing5.txt", "r");
if((pointer = fopen("testing5.txt", "r"))!= NULL)
{
    printf("No error, file successfully opened\n you may contine :)\n");
}
   else
   {printf("file could not be opened\nterminating program,...\n");
   return 0;}
   fgets(buffer,100,pointer);
   printf("%s\n", buffer);
     sscanf(buffer,"%[^*/]*/%[^//]//%[^.).)]%[^,/],/ %[^//]//%d",&id,status, &grades[0],&grades[1],&grades[2],&grades[3]);
    printf("%d\n%s\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d",id,status, grades[0],grades[1],grades[2],grades[3]);
   for (j =0; j<3; j++)
   for(k =j+1; k<4;k++)
   {
    if(grades[j]<grades[k] )
    {
        temp = grades[j];
        grades[j] = grades[k];
        grades[k] = temp;
    }
   }
   printf("\nthe grades in ascending order is \n");
   for (j =0; j<4; j++)
   {
    printf("%d\n", grades[j]);
   }
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Check the return values of the functions (e.g. `sscanf`) and use a debugger

Comment: Why are you opening the file twice?

Comment: Also, that `scanf()` format string in itself should warn you that you are doing something wrong. Just look at it, isn't it horrible? `strok_r()` and `strtol()` are your friends.

Comment: The compiler will also warn you: `../src/TestC.c:26:6: warning: format ‘%[^*/’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]` and several more.

Comment: i know about those functions, just trying to do it with every option to learn more about c

Comment: btw bluepixy is genius, she solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  sscanf("1019*/passed// 56.)100,/ 82//10\n", "%d*/%[^/]// %d.)%d,/ %d//%d",
      &id, status, &grades[0],&grades[1],&grades[2],&grades[3]);
```

Comment: is there a way for me to contact you thru messages , u seem to solve alot of my problems..ur a great help..id really appreciate it if you could aid me in the future too..

Comment: @user3151918 It can be anyone.

Comment: @user3151918 if you feel like an answer has solved your problem, you should consider upvoting/accepting it

Comment: i would have but my reputation isnt high enough  @Andrey

Comment: @user3151918 you can accept an answer to your own question regardless of your reputation

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
int grades[4]= {0}
```

to

```
char grades[4] = { 0 };
```

The warning output is pointing out the problem, don't ignore it.  You are passing the wrong data types to sscanf.